# Why is the best-practices tag not allowed on SO any more?

Tags: support, tags, best-practices

I have nothing to add to the title: Why is the [best-practices] tag not allowed on SO any more?

Comment: strongly related: [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)

Answer (score 6):

See [the official line](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) which begins:

> There are a few tags on Stack Overflow that have bugged me for a long
> time. Namely:
>
> - subjective
> - best-practices
> - beginner
>
> But I could never quite articulate what, exactly, was wrong with these
> tags. It's been bothering me more and more as time goes on.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's sad. IMHO someone has too much free time..

Comment: Let's make some use of the superflous 'free time' barb: I've created an Area 51 'Coding Best Practises' site for you. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17184/coding-best-practises

Comment: I didn't mean you. Thanks for your efforts, but I think it won't replace the abandoned tags on SO for those users who used to put them on questions about best practices in whichever field.

Comment: I'm amused to see that 'best-practices' is legal on meta, but not on SO.

Answer (score 0):

It was definitely a bad decision.

I'm just getting into PHP, and wanted to scan through the PHP questions by the [best-practices](/questions/tagged/best-practices) tag so I could ramp myself up on what's current, but it no longer exists.  Now you have to hope the text contains 'best practices'.

It would have been a natural if the tag had existed.

Comment: It's quite simple really. Just [start by browsing the highest voted questions in that tag. Then search for “best practices” within the tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/#comment-49013). This is, apparently, not a joke.