# [bestpractices] pops up to replace the banned [best-practices] on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request, blocked-tags

I've just edited out <s>five</s>**six** instances.

While I'd be happy to see such questions go, if we've going to allow the questions the tag seems less meta than some. Otherwise we need to blacklist this variant as well.

---

Links:

- [What is the best practice for loading a link/linking action into a Flash file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761934/what-is-the-best-practice-for-loading-a-link-linking-action-into-a-flash-file)
- [Best practice for project directory structure and source control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761985/best-practice-for-project-directory-structure-and-source-control)
- [WPF BackgroundWorker vs. Dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762576/wpf-backgroundworker-vs-dispatcher)
- [Limiting Form Submissions by Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762958/limiting-form-submissions-by-time)
- [Embedded YouTube code does not validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755007/embedded-youtube-code-does-not-validate)
- [MVC, Entity Framework, Business Logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763632/mvc-entity-framework-business-logic)

Comment: I think these banned tags are pointless. More and more will keep popping up, it's just like an [obscenity filter](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html).

Comment: Just like "newbie" was popping up to replace "beginner"

Comment: @NullUser: Yep. And the variants will violate our tagging best practices (heh!) to boot...

Comment: *(cough)...(cough)...* [Should some “forbidden” tags still have an active tag wiki and tag synonyms?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60343/should-some-forbidden-tags-still-have-an-active-tag-wiki-and-tag-synonyms) *...(cough)...*

Comment: `b3$7-pr@ct1c3z`

Comment: @Null: So what you're saying is that instead of relying on a filter, we should just actively turf users who abuse the tag system?  I completely agree.

Answer (score 9):

It was a bad idea to get rid of the [best-practices](/questions/tagged/best-practices).  It is exactly the tag that should be applied to best-practice posts.  So, for example; if someone wants to get best practices for embedding youtube code, then they can search on `youtube` and [best-practices](/questions/tagged/best-practices).

Related Post: [Why is the best-practices tag not allowed on SO any more?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60191/why-is-the-best-practices-tag-not-allowed-on-so-any-more)

Comment: Yes, the fanatical hunting down of meta tags is getting a bit silly at this point. What if Jeff or Joel suddenly decide that they like meta tags again?  Will the community here change its tune again?

Comment: @Harry: presumable the team can work up queries to help in restoring them. And I'm glad that this will not be my problem.

Comment: Except that the entire concept of "best practices" is intrinsically nonsense.  We might as well have a `[plz-send-teh-codez]` tag.

Comment: @Aarobot:  Some people do seem to believe in them, but there are two ideas that I've seen confounded.  Some things considered "best practices" are fundamentals like version control, while other things are simply mediocrity.  Until I see a coherent definition that strikes me as useful, I'm agreeing with you.