# Meta-tag synonyms (e.g. [best-practices], [bestpractices], [programming-practices])

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags

Since the `[best-practices]` tag was banned, a handful of synonym tags have been creeping onto SO in its place. For example, `[bestpractices]`, `[programming-practices]` and `[patterns-and-practices]`.

Are these considered to be synonymous, or is there a fine line between them that makes some of these OK but `[best-practices]` not?  If the former, then should they be added to the ban list?

Comment: Related: [bestpractices pops up to replace the banned best-practices on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65198/).

Comment: @dmckee: Curses. I knew this question must've been asked before, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: The previous version was inconclusive, however. And as you point out the overflowosphere keeps thinking of new variants...