# Which community should I use for best practices regarding TFS version control?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question regarding how to set up my TFS directories, but it's not a right-or-wrong-answer question.  Which StackExchange community should I pose my question to?

Comment: From Meta.Programmers.SE: [Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6311/40980) - one should be able to reapply that to TFS.  Note that 'best practices' tend to be a rather vaporous thing - they are the maybe right answer to some unknown problem... but without knowing what they solve they could be the completely wrong thing to do in another situation. One should instead ask about how to solve specific problems.  See also [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/213963).

Comment: @MichaelT there seem to be generalised version of that guidance, [Where does my tool question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go)

Comment: Nowhere.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/142354#142354

Comment: @gnat yep. Saw that one too. I have a bit of a bias for the git one partly because I wrote it and partly because I call out some examples of stereotypical questions that are on topic on each site within that domain. I believe that this makes it a bit easier to decide what type of question goes where - especially in the case that it is on topic for Programmers.SE.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow is fine. However...

> [If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Make sure you're posing your question as a request for information, NOT opinions. "Best practices" are opinions, superstitions that folks cling to in lieu of understanding the problems they hope to solve. Don't ask us to tell you how to ward off demons; ask us how to accomplish a task.

Comment: Right, I do want an explanation in this case.

Comment: For reference, the question was posted on Programmers: [How can I organize my TFS structure such that a one-off project that pulls files from another project can be easily managed?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/308000/40980) - and on a 0th glance, that looks like a reasonable question. When people start asking about 'best practices' on meta site recommendations, it gets me worried what will show up. I would like to congratulate @dfoverdx for being on the "much better than expected" side of my expectations. Thank you.

Comment: Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/142354#142354

Comment: Demons, zombies, whatever @Won't

Comment: @Won't "those who invalidate automatically, _by keywords trigger_, fall in the very trap warned about in canonical post referred in this question: 'spotting a herd in the distance and going trotting off after it'" ([how to ask a “best practice” question that is acceptable to the community?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7091/making-best-practices-questions-more-palatable-how-to-ask-a-best-practice-q/7113#comment21307_7113))