# Which website to ask question and get suggestions related to programming language (i.e. Laravel) ? )

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want some programming suggestion, say for example, in [Laravel Programming language](https://laravel.com/), I have a question about whether we should or must remove **public** folder or not for best practices. Shall we remove it or not whether I am on local server and go on to upload on live server.

I am afraid to ask this question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) as I can end up losing my reputation which I do not want as I do not have much.

So where can I ask those **need suggestion** kind of programming questions? Here on Meta or somewhere else?

Comment: related: [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)

Answer (score 4):

Best practices don't do well generally because they are often too broad or primarily opinion based, both close reasons on Stack Overflow.

I don't think your questions are a good fit for any site. Maybe if you are a regular in a chat room regarding that subject, you can ask it there.

If you have enough reputation to ask on Stack Overflow Meta (you will need 5), you can ask if the specific question you want to ask is deemed on-topic, but I highly doubt it.

Comment: so you are basically saying, go for a chat option ?

Comment: I say: for sure don't just post it on the main site. Depending on the chat room they might warmly welcome you or not. Maybe some discussion forum?

Comment: Ah! got you .. can have a go at Laravel discussion forum or related places.