# Where do I ask a question about the best way to develop or code something?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I sometimes need to ask code questions on which is the best way to do something or code something.

On Stack Overflow I get downvoted, not sure if there is a community on Stack Exchange where to ask.

To give an example, the question I need to ask is:

"In a PHP / MySQL application which is the best way to save some code snippets? Should I save them in database or would it be better to let the user upload some files with the snippet?"

I'm pretty sure that if I ask this question on Stack Overflow I will get downvoted because it doesn't have any code example or code puzzle to solve, but is a generic question instead.

EDIT: I'm not sure is a best practice question, it may be.
I can technically solve it both ways but one may could be the wrong one.
Is more like asking if i an store my images in database, technically you can but i would say is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: You need to narrow down "best". You need to give a context in which to measure this "best" (readability? speed of coding? security? performance? lines of code? something else?)

Comment: You also don't mention any constraints - what are your constraints for the design? What you have there is overly broad, can have any number of "correct" answers.

Comment: "best practice" questions are off topic in whole of SE being opinion based.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the example question. It sounds like you're looking for a version control system, where you'd branch off a version that includes your snippet.

Comment: Mine is a "best practice" question on witch way i should chose to do something. The problem can be solve in both ways but one may reveal the wrong one later on.

Comment: You cannot sanely ask SO users to answer such a question.  As posted above, it's grossly under-specified.  If you added a reasonable requirement spec, hardware repc, constraints etc, you will get closed for 'too broad', TL;DR and, probably 'get a freelance!'

Comment: see also [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)